# PHP SQL COUNT AND GET DATA

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, count

I would like get the id and the number of id. So, I write this command sql:

```
SELECT count(id), id 
FROM tblExample
```

It's doesn't work. Have you a solution for me ? For to get the value of my id and the number of id.

Or a function PHP for count my resultset.

Comment: You want count of **each** `ID` or **all** `ID`? I assume the `Id` is unique in your table!

Comment: What RDBMS is this? Is it MySQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add a `GROUP BY id`:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id)
FROM tblExample
GROUP BY id;
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/657cb/1)

---

**Update:**

The query you posted:

```
SELECT count(id), id 
FROM tblExample;
```

Won't work in most of the RDBMS and it shouldn't. In SQL Server, you will got an error; saying that:

> Column 'id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

<strike>**Strangely though**, MySQL allow this(The OP didn't say what RDBMS he is using), and in this case, it will get an arbitrary value (this is also depends on an option to set), for the `id` column, and the `COUNT` in this case would be all the id's count.</strike>

But it is not recommended to do so.

Comment: Can you explain this behavior? I mean GROUP BY. Is it due to aggregate function COUNT?

Comment: @raheelshan - Yes, this is because of the `COUNT` function without a group by, see my edit.

Comment: @WhitneyR. - How it doesn't work? Can you please show me the exact query you tried, the errors you got if any? And if possible some sample data and the results that you want to get from these sample data.